# Tableau - Finding index membership overlap

Tags: tableau-api

My dataset is two fixed income indices feeding into Tableau via one Excel document. Within the spreadsheet is a column containing "index A" or "index B" depending on which index the line item relates to. I need a way of finding the companies that appear in both indices, is anyone able to shed any light? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the company name is consistent (you're probably using a ticker so this shouldn't be a prob) you can do this with a simple LOD calc. All of those companies that have more than one unique entry in the Index column are in both indices. Try this and adapt for your data source:

```
{FIXED [Company]:COUNTD([Index])}
```

You can use this to isolate companies with both indices:

```
{FIXED [Company]:COUNTD([Index])}>1
```

Put that on the filters and set to True. It should exclude all companies in only 1 index.